# Google VRView for Web - Adding Hotspots

Tags: javascript, google-vr, webvr, google-vr-sdk

**Project:** Basic website, display panorama image with Google's VRView for Web and add hotspots.

**Issue:** Panorama displays fine, haven't been able to add hotspots, documentation is poor + googling has resulted in little results for approx. 1.5 hours.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
function onVrViewLoad() {
  var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
    image: 'uploads/pano.jpg',
    is_stereo: false
  });

  vrView.addHotspot('hotspot-one', {
         pitch: 30, // In degrees. Up is positive.
          yaw: 20, // In degrees. To the right is positive.
          radius:   0.05, // Radius of the circular target in meters.
          distance: 2, // Distance of target from camera in meters.
    });
}

</script>

<div id="vrview">
</div>
```

**Request:** Has anybody been able to implement these hotspots? I have also tried adding on the click of a button, to no avail. Tried in both a laravel server and a basic html implementation, to no avail.

**Supporting Documentation/Examples:**

- https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web
- http://googlevr.github.io/vrview/examples/hotspots/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to add your code into on ready

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
function onVrViewLoad() {
  var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
    image: 'uploads/pano.jpg',
    is_stereo: false
  });
vrView.on('ready',function(){
  vrView.addHotspot('hotspot-one', {
         pitch: 30, // In degrees. Up is positive.
          yaw: 20, // In degrees. To the right is positive.
          radius:   0.05, // Radius of the circular target in meters.
          distance: 2, // Distance of target from camera in meters.
    });
}
});

</script>

<div id="vrview">
</div>
```

Comment: brother could you please help me 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166181/control-button-on-google-vr-view